# Why does no one answer my questions?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I am not getting any responses on any question I've asked in the last two days? Why is that? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: No idea, but you do ask a lot more questions than you answer.  Besides, this one isn't programming related.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: I guess this question got down-voted before migrated here. It's relevent here though is kind of a dup. I'll try to neutralise the vote. It's -4 at the time of this comment which I thought is bit harsh IMHO :P

Comment: Neutralised at last, cool!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, asking question is an art. You need not have perfect command of English.

Here are a few pointers (by no means exhaustive):

- Have a good question title, so people have a good idea of the context and they will know if it's something they have the expertise/interest to answer.
- Relevent tags, reason same as above and also ease search and those who browse by tags.
- Structure your question properly especially if it is long and complex.
- Can the question be spilt into 2 or more so each portion can have discrete answer? Give it some thought. If the splitted questions are have related context, hyperlink them up.
- Give respect to those who attempt to read and answer your question, they have no obligation so make it easy for them to read and be polite :)

The list goes on and on, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you may want to consider is to edit your question. You can take on board comments people have made that will make it a better question, or simply change it yourself.

By making the question active again, it returns to the top of some views.

Another way, if you *really* want more answers and you have enough rep, is to offer a bounty.